# What is the difference between 'ssr:false' vs 'target:static' in NuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxtjs2

To generate a **static site** using NuxtJS, it seems there are **2 options to set**: `ssr:false` and `target:static` inside the NuxtJS config file (`nuxt.config.js`) which practically do the sme thing? Why both of them exist if they do the same thing? or is there any difference between the two options.

Answer (score 2):

`ssr: false` is used if you want to have only an SPA.
On the other hand, `target: 'static'` is used if you want to have SSG, rather than regular SSR (with `taget: 'server'`).
It means that you could have a mix of:

- `ssr: true` + `'static'` aka SSG
- `ssr: true` + `'server'` aka SSR
- `ssr: false` + `'static'` aka SPA

Feel free to make a search on Stackoverflow to have more details.

---

To answer the question, static can be SSG or SPA, but the second one doesn't have all the SEO benefits etc, it's pretty much a regular Vue app (and you're loosing quite some benefits of Nuxt).